# Setenv list edit Centos 5.11

Tags: linux, centos, environment-variables

Been looking for an answer but nothing seems to give me a simple one-liner answer (I am not a computer genius).

I want to edit one of the variables (I see them with setenv commant) on a centos 5.11 server.

I have tried:

```
bash -c "export MXIB_MAILLOGTO1=new@test.com; echo \$MXIB_MAILLOGTO1"
(also tried) bash -c "set MXIB_MAILLOGTO1=new@test.com; export MXIB_MAILLOGTO1; echo \$MXIB_MAILLOGTO1"
```

Above still prints the old value, not new@test.com

Comment: A child process  (that you start with "bash -c") cannot change its parent's environment.

Answer (score 1):

No need to start a subshell, do it in the current one.

```
MXIB_MAILLOGTO1='new@test.com'
echo $MXIB_MAILLOGTO1
```